# Design Pattern for "Context Sensitive" Right Click Menu

Tags: menu, design-patterns

What is a design pattern I can use for generating "context-sensitive" right click menus ? I have in mind a "Windows Explorer"-like application where a user can right click on a folder and get a list of menu items but right click on a drive and get a totally different list. 
What design pattern should I use ?  Would the factory design pattern be appropiate for handling such a menu ? 
Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to check out the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and the [builder-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) and [factory-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). In pseudocode you may do something like this:

```
OnRightClick(Item ClickedItem) {
    ContextMenu = MenuBuilder.Visit( ClickedItem );
    Choice = ContextMenu.Show();
}
```

The `MenuBuilder` would construct an appropriate context method based on the item it visits.